# Regular expression NIC

Tags: php, regex

Can you please help me in validation a mauritian NIC.

```
[1 capital letter][dateofBirth][6 numbers][1 capital letter]
```

Note: date of birth format: `ddmmyy`

I tried this one:

```
/^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{12}[A-Z]{1}$/
```

But how do i validate the date of birth in the NIC? Thank you

Comment: Please give examples of some valid NIC.

Comment: note that `[...]{1}` is redundant. a character class (`[]`) will always match a single character.

Comment: Example: D160289784495A

Comment: In `160289784495`, `16` is day `02` month,  and `89` year?

Comment: Yes @chris85, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to validate the date, you'll have a hard time doing so just with regex. But, fortunately, PHP has a [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.checkdate.php) function. You just have to extract the day, month and year, which should be pretty easy but will slightly change your regex. Don't forget to put parenthesis around each element (day, month, year), to be able to retrieve them.

If I'm not mistaken, your regex should be something like that :

```
/^[A-Z]([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})[0-9]{6}[A-Z]$/
```

Then check the date, so:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z]([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})[0-9]{6}[A-Z]$/', 'D160289784495A', $match);

var_dump(checkdate($match[2], $match[1], $match[3]));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was typing so I just edited it in.

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Can you please explain what $match[2] is doing? Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: preg_match can modify its third argument to contain all the elements matched. The first element will be the element that matches the whole pattern. The following elements, if any, will be the different elements put in parenthesis in the regex pattern.

Comment: So as the pattern for a NIC is ddmmyyyy, match[1] will be dd, match[2] mm and match[3] yyyy. And then you have to properly order them for the checkdate function.

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thank you very much. I marked it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Not for range of dates, years and months.**

You cannot simply check ranges of month, days and years with regex. For that you will have use some library function. Following regex will do a **preliminary** job of validating the **format of NIC**. After that proceed to checking the validity of dates.

This regex should check the format `^[A-Z]\d{12}[A-Z]$`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG2mC5/1)**

Note that in your format

`[1 capital letter][dateofBirth][6 numbers][1 capital letter]`

Since format of date of birth is `ddmmyy` it's counted only as 6 numbers so your format is actually like this

`[1 capital letter][12 numbers][1 capital letter]`

Comment: But the first 6 number are date of birth. how do i validate that
Example: D160298190098A
Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @Student: You cannot validate **Range** of years, months and days by simple regex.

Comment: Got your point. But if user enters D421329184478A, this should not be accepted..

Comment: @Student: Yea that's the problem with regex. You cannot **Simply** validate range of numbers. You will have to extract the date part. Then arrange in `dd/mm/yy` format and check with some **Library function**. Use of simple regex here is not enough.

Comment: @Student Use regexp for validating simple character patters. If you need to check numeric ranges, use numeric operators.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: @Student: Am glad I could be of help.